# Как определить является ли массив палиндромом

Tags: java

[Wiki:Палиндром](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC)
Пример массива-палиндрома:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Бегленько так:

```
boolean b = true;
int len = your_array.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
  if (your_array[i] != you_array[len - i - 1]) {
    b = false;
    break;
  }
if (b) System.out.println('Да') else System.out.println('Нет');
```

Comment: только не `your_array.length()`, а просто `your_array.length`

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: еще вопросик зачем в строке "you_array[len - i - 1])" мы отнимаем "i", без єтого тоже работает.

Comment: boolean b = true;
  for (int k = 0; k < mass.length / 2; k++) {
    if (mass[k] != mass[mass.length - 1 ]) {
      b = false;
      System.out.println("Ne polindrom");
      break;
    }
  if (b)
   System.out.println("Polindrom");

Comment: > еще вопросик зачем в строке "you_array[len - i - 1])" 

нужно ведь сравнивать первый элемент с последним, второй с предпоследним. Если сделать так `mass[k] != mass[mass.length - 1 ]`, то будут находиться палиндромы двух типов - с четным количеством элементов, где все равны или нечетным, где все равны, кроме центрального - он может быть любым.

Comment: спасибо, уже сам понял, при массиве типа 1 2 2 1 выдает белеберду в моей вариации))

Comment: А мне такая запись цикла нравится больше

     for (int i = 0, j = pal.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
 if (pal[i] != pal[j]) {
          ....

Answer (score 1):

Короткий способ, но наверно не такой быстрый, как предложил [[[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)- просто разворачиваем массив и сравниваем (скорее всего третьего способа не существует (адекватного))

```
function isPalindrom(Object[] arr) {
    return Arrays.compare(arr, ArrayUtils.reverse(arr));
};
```

---

**UPD**
Хочу еще добавить, что этот способ не так плох, как кажется сначала. В Java конечно способ [[[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) всегда быстрее моего, но вот в скриптовых языках вроде питона или JavaScript быстрее вызвать две нативные функции, чем гонять в цикле данные, вот пример для питона:

```
from time import clock
from random import randint
max_int = 2**31-1

t0 = clock()
a1 = [randint(0, max_int) for i in range(0, 5000000)]
a1+=reversed(a1)
t1 = clock()
print (t1-t0)
b1= a1==a1[::-1]
t2 = clock()
print (t2 - t1, b1)
c1=True
for i in range(int(len(a1)/2)):
    if (a1[i]!=a1[-i-1]):
        c1=False
        break
t3=clock()
print (t3-t2, c1)
```

Результат такой:

```
15.246594007127472
0.22515124632224293 True
1.5805880061266198 True
```

То есть имея большой палиндромный массив мы весьма существенно выиграем в скорости, если вызовем всего две нативные функции- разворот массива и сравнение.

Comment: весь массив то сравнивать не нужно, можно только половину!

Comment: Третий способ - разворачивать только половину массива и сравнивать с неразвернутой другой половиной.